# Teamcity build with multiple vcs roots

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have an web application in first git repository, and some client designs for it in second git repository. Every client design pushed in it's own branch. Both repos attached to build configuration, and I want to select which branch of second repo must be checkouted, when I run build on some branch of first repo.

Now, always default branch of second repo checkouted (how described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches)). On [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-Branch-RelatedParameters) page I found that exists parameter `teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID>`, but it is for reading, not for setting up before build.

How to do this build? Or may be other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the checkout branch in the VCS config. If you don't want this to be a fixed value you can set it to a configuration variable, say `%CheckoutBranch%` and then for each build that uses this vcs root you'll have to provide a build parameter so the checkout can be performed.

like this:

[image]